# How to change API BEGIN_ARRAY to BEGIN_OBJECT in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

This is my service:

```
class NewsAPIService {
private val BASE_URL = "http://newsapi.org/v2/"
private val api = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build()
    .create(NewsAPI::class.java)

fun getData():Single<List<news58>>{
    return api.getNews()
}}
```

This is my interface:

```
interface NewsAPI {
@GET("top-headlines?category=sports&apiKey=42862811f4c94e82988aaa326dad8f4c")
fun getNews():Single<List<news58>>
}
```

This is my `viewModel`:

```
private fun getDataFromAPI(){
    newsLoading.value = true
    disposible.add(
        newsApiService.getData()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<List<news58>>(){
                override fun onSuccess(t: List<news58>) {
                    getNews.value = t
                newsLoading.value = false
                    newsError.value = false

                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    newsLoading.value = false
                    newsError.value = true
                 e.printStackTrace()
                }}))}
```

When I try to download data I get this error:

```
2020-04-07 12:48:20.148 16738-16738/com.msamil.newspaper4 W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
2020-04-07 12:48:20.148 16738-16738/com.msamil.newspaper4 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
```

How can I fix it? This is a new app. I'm trying to learn it but it doesn't work like that.

Comment: can you please share your response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is only because of your get List from your API response but, your response is just sent you a JSONObject, not a List.

So, in your case might be you have to use like below

```
fun getData():Single<ews58>{
    return api.getNews()
}}
```

in your interface

```
interface NewsAPI {
@GET("top-headlines?category=sports&apiKey=42862811f4c94e82988aaa326dad8f4c")
fun getNews():Single<news58>
}
```

**Update**

ViewModel

```
private fun getDataFromAPI(){
    newsLoading.value = true
    disposible.add(
        newsApiService.getData()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<news58>(){
                override fun onSuccess(t: news58) {
                   // your code

                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    newsLoading.value = false
                    newsError.value = true
                 e.printStackTrace()
                }}))}
```

Comment: but like that I don't get any error but I dont get any respons because news58 is my Model and ı use it in my recyclerView Adapter how can ı fix it ?

Comment: I think you need to change in your `ViewModel` in `getDataFromAPI()` methods.

Comment: I changed it but now there is some problem with adapter because ı dont see anything

Comment: Just debug and check that you get a response in your view model.